# clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreTelephony'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-telephony

I'm trying to build my app, It was all working fine until I built and archived a version to send to Apple (Which built fine but then Apple couldn't launch it) Since then I keep getting errors such as:

> clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreTelephony'

Or:

> clang: error: no such file or directory: '__entitlements'

I've searched through my project and cannot find any mention of CoreTelephony or __entitlements. I currently cannot build my app or test it. I've spent hours searching through my project but just cannot find anything to do with these files.
Can anyone advise me on what I can do to get rid of these errors?

Many thanks.
Andrew

Comment: did you enable the `Voice Over IP` background mode for your application?

Comment: Nope :-( Only got Background Fetch, but thats been enabled for a while.

Comment: try adding it, and let me know.

Comment: Currently, it's throwing another issue: ld: framework not found -lstdc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Going to bang my head on the wall soon!

Comment: clean the project and build again

Comment: Yeah i've tried that already.